# wirecloud / fiware widget adding list to preferences

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I'm working on a widget in the fiware lab and I want to use the the list option in the preferences. 
I used text, boolean and number before, but there isn't documented how to define the options.

How could I do that? In the config.xml? Is it an array or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right there were not documentation about how to add list preferences, thanks for reporting it. We have improve our ["Adding preferences" tutorial](https://conwet.fi.upm.es/docs/display/wirecloud/Adding+preferences) wiki page to include more details on how to define list preferences and soon those changes will be included on other guides and on the FIWARE's E-learning platform ;-).

Anyway, here is an example of how to define a list preference including their options:

```xml
<widget xmlns="http://wirecloud.conwet.fi.upm.es/ns/macdescription/1" vendor="Wirecloud" name="Test" version="1.0">
  <details>
    ...
  </details>
  <preferences>
    <preference name="list" type="list" label="list" description="list preference" default="default">
      <option value="default" label="Default value"/>
      <option value="1" label="value1"/>
      <option value="2" label="value2"/>
    </preference>
  </preferences>
  ...
</widget>
```